# List of Links: Using Event Listeners to Keep My HTML Structure As Simple As Possible

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, hyperlink, event-listener

I've been doing the following for as long as I can remember:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="somewhere">Some text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Since it's just a list of links, nothing else, I know I can do this to simplify the structure:

```
<ul>
  <li onclick="window.location.href='somewhere'">Some text</li>
</ul>
```

I've just lightened the HTML structure by 50%. If I have 100 rows, I’d have 100 elements instead of 200.

Of course, I should use event listeners instead on inline `onclick`, but I don't know how... How do I use event listeners (instead of inline `onclick`) to create a list of links? See [here](http://cubiq.org/you-shall-not-flicker) for the motivation for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind using jQuery, you could have a look at basic jQuery tutorials of binding click handlers to elements. This way, you can set an `onclick` to **all** `<li>` at once:

http://jsfiddle.net/7zba5/1/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li data-url="http://www.google.com">Google</li>
    <li data-url="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</li>
    <li data-url="http://www.superuser.com">Super User</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).data('url');
});
```

Comment: This is really concise and clean.  Is there any benefit to declaring the function once and setting pointers? http://jsfiddle.net/kLmq5/3/

Comment: @RSG: In my honest opinion, I don't find yours much simpler. First of all, the `data()` function is to be used for `data-` attributes. Secondly, the function is just one line of code, so no real benefit of creating a standalone function from it.